# ZeroMQ Choosing Correct Client-Worker Model for a Call Center

Tags: perl, design-patterns, zeromq

I have a project that needs to be written in Perl so I've chosen ZeroMQ.

There is a single client program, generating work for a variable number of workers. The workers are real human operators who will complete a task then request a new task. The job of the client program is keep all available workers busy all day. It's a call center.

So each worker can only process one task at time, and there may be some time before requesting a new task. And the number of workers may vary during the day.

The client needs to keep a queue of tasks ready to give to workers as and when they request them. Whenever the client queue gets low the client can generate more tasks to top-up the queue.

What design pattern (i.e. what ZeroMQ Socket combination) should I use for this? I've skimmed through all the patterns in the 0MQ Guide and can't find anything that matches this.

Thanks

Comment: ZMQ looks more like for inter-process communication. SQL table can be easily used as queue, and it has persistence.

Comment: Thanks. That's where we started from, unfortunately we ended up with locking problems on the MySQL tables.

Comment: `select for update` should not cause problems. Redis lists can also be used as queues.

Comment: Sounds like the Load Balancing Broker from The Guide would be a good fit. Maybe extended with some of the reliability patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sure.  <sup>... there is not a single, solo Archetype to match the Requirement List</sup> 
use several ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Patterns

Typical software Project uses many ZeroMQ sockets ( with various Archetypes ) as a certain form of node-node signalisation and message-passing platform.

It is fair to note, that automated Load-Balancers may work fine for automated processes, but not always so for processes, executed by Humans or interacting with Humans.

Humans ( both the Call centre Agents and their Line-Supervisors ) introduce another layer of requirements - sometimes with a need to introduce non-just-Round-Robin workload distribution logic, sometimes need to switch a call from Agent A to another Agent B ( which a trivial archetype will simply not be capable of and might get into troubles, if it's hardwired-logic runs into a collision ( mutually blocked `REQ-REP` stale-mate being one such example ).

So simply forget to wait for one super-powered archetype, but rather create a smart network of behaviours, that will cover your distributed-computing problem desired event-handling.

There are many other aspects, one ought learn before taking the first ZeroMQ socket into service.

- failure resillience
- performance scaling
- latency-profiling ( high-priority voice-traffic, vs. low-priority logging )
- watchdog acknowledgements and timeout situations handling
- cross-compatibility issues ( version 2.1x vs 3.x vs 4.+ API )
- processing robustness against a malfunctioning agent / malicious attack / deadly spurious traffic storms ... to name just a few of problems

all of which has some built-ins in the ZeroMQ toolbox, some of which may need some advanced thinking, so as to handle known constraints.

---

### The Best Next Step?

A would advocate for a fabulous Pieter HINTJENS' book "Code Connected, Volume 1" -- for everyone, who is serious into distributed processing, this is a must-read -- do not hesitate to [check other my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20is%3Aanswer) to find a direct URL to a **PDF-version** of this ZeroMQ Bible.

Worth time and one's tears and sweat.